# Changing Custom Files Name from Accect Type

Tags: html, mime-types

I have a input of type file with custom accept types

```
<input type='file' accept=".csv, .xls">
```

When I open up the file dialog there is the drop down for the accept types, which says custom files.

[image: CustomFileTypeImage]

is there a way to override the 'custom files' text to say something else or if this is even possible?

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this.  If there is a way, it is difficult to google-fu it.  Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Anj Yeah, everytime I google it it just comes up with html to accept custom types, I haven't found anything yet. Post something though if you do!